# I have a trouble after trying to parallelize data using nn.Dataparallel

Tags: pytorch, typeerror

I didn't have any probelm without data parallelization, but after I put JUST A ONE LINE "model = nn.DataParallel(model)" the error message "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable" comes. If I push out that damn line the source works clean. plz help me

I can't do anything but just mad. I search that google and there are some ways to solve that error message but I can't do anything. Because nn.Dataparallel is already used by other coders. Sorry English is not my mothertongue.

```
    if use_cuda:
            [[[model = nn.DataParallel(model)]]]
            model = model.cuda()
            criterion = criterion.cuda()
            print('cuda is used')
```

I just put `model = nn.DataParallel(model)` and error comes right after.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/scrcdeep2/YBJ/espnet_myself/Main.py", line 119, in 
>       train(loader, model_, criterion_, optimizer_, use_cuda_, pretrained=None)
>
> File "/home/scrcdeep2/YBJ/espnet_myself/Main.py", line 83, in train
>       outputs = model(inputs)
>
> File "/home/scrcdeep2/YBJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 493, in **call**
>       result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
>    File "/home/scrcdeep2/YBJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", line 151, in forward
>       replicas = self.replicate(self.module, self.device_ids[:len(inputs)])
>
> File "/home/scrcdeep2/YBJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", line 156, in replicate
>       return replicate(module, device_ids)
>
> File "/home/scrcdeep2/YBJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/replicate.py", line 114, in replicate
>       modules = list(network.modules())
>
> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: This means that `nn.DataParallel` is not a function but a list. Investigate by printing the list, look at the `nn` object documentation / source code, etc.

Comment: sorry... I can't understand what exactly you said. Can you give me a simple example? In the pytorch documents, there isn't what i want to know. Am I need to add more codes to parallelize the data?

Comment: Looking at [nn.DataParallel documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html) this is indeed a function. Could you edit your post to add the result of `print(type(nn.DataParallel))` (call this command before trying to call DataParallel) ? Also doing x = f(x) seems suspect.

Comment: <class 'type'> has came out. you said x = f(x) seems wrong but almost every example is same as me. very thank for your answers again and sorry for my short english. OK I'll check that doc again.

Comment: Looking at your profile I understand that your are a student, so maybe you should ask a teacher or another student ? I am not a pytorch expert so I am afraid I cannot help more.

Comment: Gabriel Devillers Really thx For U. I appreciate for your effort

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem, because I've set `moules = [list]`.

I changed my code like this:

```
def __init__(self, embedding_size, activation_function='relu'):
    super().__init__()
    self.act_fn = getattr(F, activation_function)
    self.embedding_size = embedding_size
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 32, 4, stride=2)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 4, stride=2)
    self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 4, stride=2)
    self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(128, 256, 4, stride=2)
    self.fc = nn.Identity() if embedding_size == 1024 else nn.Linear(1024, embedding_size)
    if not args.MultiGPU:
      self.modules = [self.conv1, self.conv2, self.conv3, self.conv4]
```